# Getting all class attributes. How?

Tags: class, reflection, attributes, abap

I want to read all the attributes from a class in ABAP, maybe via reflection?
After that I want to filter out all constants from a specified type.
How can i do this?

I know that i can read the all items of a structure via `assign component of structure`, also I can read them via a function module which reads the field catalog from a structure.

How to do this with the attributes of an class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [RTTS](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abenrtti.htm) for this. You'll get an instance of CL_ABAP_OBJECTDESCR (either a CLASSDESCR or an INTFDESCR, depending on what kind of reference you throw in) that has some public attributes that contain the attributes of the class in question.

Comment: thanks! works fine :) i already heard about this, but couldn't remember.